# remove object from NSMutableArray by key

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@{@"name":@"Jenny",@"age":@23},@{@"name":@"Daisy",@"age":@27},nil];
```

Is it possible to remove object by key in the array's dictionary object?

For example. remove object by age = 27

Comment: You mean you want to delete the second dictionary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To filter objects out of an NSArray, call `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`:

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"name":@"Jenny",@"age":@23},@{@"name":@"Daisy",@"age":@27}];
NSArray *array2 =
  [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
   [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *d) {
      return ![[obj valueForKey:@"age"] isEqual:@27];
  }]];
```

Now `array2` is the desired array - it is the first array without the one whose age is 27.

By the way, I know this is not what you asked, but that sort of thing is a *great* reason to switch to Swift. It is soooooo much simpler; this sort of problem is like a living neon technicolor advertisement for Swift:

```
let array = [["name":"Jenny", "age":23],["name":"Daisy", "age":27]]
let array2 = array.filter {$0["age"] != 27}
```

Comment: Very interesting, never used predicates outside of core data before. Does this still perform a search with n iterations worst-case under the covers, or is it more efficient than a normal iterative process?

Comment: @Mike It's just a loop.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `NSPredicate` to create a new array that's missing the unwanted entry. `NSPredicate` is similar to a database query where the input NSArray represents the database, and the output array is the response to the query.

```
NSArray *array = @[  @{@"name":@"Jenny",@"age":@23},
                     @{@"name":@"Daisy",@"age":@27}  ];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"age != 27"];
NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSLog( @"%@", array );
NSLog( @"%@", filtered );
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if there's a more direct method or not, but one way to do it would be to simply iterate through the array and test the values. You can't mutate an array while enumerating, meaning you cant remove an object while iterating through it, so one method is to obtain the index of the object that matches your criteria, and if you find one, break, and remove the item at that index. Something like the following:

```
NSInteger indexToDelete = -1;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
   NSDictionary *dict = array[i];

   if ([dict[@"age"] integerValue] == 27) {
      indexToDelete = i;
      break;      
   }
}

if (indexToDelete > 0) {
   [array removeObjectAtIndex:indexToDelete];
}
```

Intrigued by the other answers using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`, I was curious about performance and decided to do a side-by-side performance test using Xcode's `measureBlock` feature. Iterating through an array of 1,000 dictionaries, removing one item that matches an integer value from each array, and comparing when the item is very close to the beginning of the array, the middle of the array, and the end of the array, both versions tended to complete within a few *thousandths* of a second of the other, with the predicate filter being very slightly faster in every case. (We're talking around .269 seconds vs .261 seconds)

With that in mind, I would think that neither is *better* than the other in any major sense, it just comes down to preference. I do think the filteredArrayUsingPredicate method is cleaner though. Just some additional food for thought for anyone curious, and gave me a reason to try out the measureBlock feature on my own. :)

Comment: Something to consider: what if the input array has multiple entries where `age == 27`?

Comment: Very good point, if this was the case, and you wanted to remove all of them, just remove the break.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you'll have to loop through each item and do a manual test against each object, which may be fine depending on the size of data you're dealing with and the complexity of your use cases.

Alternatively, consider storing the data in a sqlite database and querying against it if it's practical for you.

Comment: You'll just want to make sure you don't mutate while enumerating.